# Как решить ошибку clickhouse Cannot load data for command line suggestions?

Tags: база-данных, clickhouse

Внезапно, в очередной раз запуская clickhouse я наткнулся на ошибку, которая по сути убила мне clickhouse.

Cannot load data for command line suggestions: Code: 107. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::ErrnoException. DB::ErrnoException: Cannot open file ./metadata/SmartHouse.sql, errno: 2, strerror: No such file or directory. (FILE_DOESNT_EXIST) (version 23.7.4.5 (official build))

Эта ошибка появляется при входе в clickhouse-client. Не зависимо от того, захожу ли я под root или обычным пользователем.
Использую Ubuntu 20.04.
До сегодня все работало прекрасно.

**Удаление и установка не помогают.**

**Команды, которыми удалял:**
apt purge clickhouse-client clickhouse-server

sudo rm -rf /etc/clickhouse-server/
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/clickhouse/
sudo rm -rf /var/log/clickhouse-server/

**Так же появляется ошибка, когда я пытаюсь сделать select from**

:) Cannot load data for command line suggestions: Code: 107. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::ErrnoException. DB::ErrnoException: Cannot open file ./metadata/SmartHouse.sql, errno: 2, strerror: No such file or directory. (FILE_DOESNT_EXIST) (version 23.7.4.5 (official build))

**в ./metadata файлы были**

В конце концов я не выдержал и сам удалил ./metadata
Но и это не помогло.

Comment: Добавили бы недостающую схему SmartHouse.sql, а затем удалили бы эту таблицу через cli